# Visualforce input validation best practices

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have multiple Visualforce pages with inputText that needs to be validated that:

> 1. Correct datatype
> 2. Correct length
> 3. Regex (ssn, phone number)

What is the best way to do the validation?

> 1. Custom validation class (Helper class)
> 2. Validation rules
> 3. Javascript validation

Any recommended validation classes that could be used?

Comment: for validation rules, check the SFDC doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/ and http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/7/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf

Comment: @crop1645 very familiar with validation rules. Looking more for best practices as if I have multiple fields I have to set validation rules for each field which doesn't make sense as allot of duplication. Also changes are not easy to manage as I have to change each field individually.

Comment: ah, well, if using common validation logic, use a utility validation class unless you want to validate at browser level, then use jQuery or other JS solution - folks at stackoverflow can help on this approach

Comment: Helper classes for sure, easy for the most part and most importantly reuseable

Comment: @EricSSH can you recommend some helper classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm posting this as an answer because I'm showing you code, but this is only one solution to many.  This is meant for a custom controller that is handled by a button on your Visualforce page.. So say you have button `Submit` on your VF page, you would check what ever data
before you save by using your getters and setters that is coming from your inputText.  This was my solution which was a VF Page controlled by a custom controller.  Granted you won't be using this exact code, this just may give you ideas to create your own

```
VF PAGE
<apex:pageMessages id="feedback" escape="false" />

public void prepareDataForSave()
{
    Boolean result = true;
    missingDataError = '';

    if(transportationWrapper.transportRequested)
    {
        if(transportationWrapper.type == 'None')
        {
            missingDataError += '<br />  ' + VEHICLE_TYPE_MUST_BE_SELECTED;
            result = false;
        }
    }

    if(specSelected)
    {
        if(tripWrapper.amenityAmmount.Budget__c <= 0)
        {
            missingDataError += '<br />  ' + BUDGET_IS_REQUIRED;
            result = false;
        }

        if(String.isBlank(specialAmenitiesWrapper.description))
        {
            missingDataError += '<br />  ' + DESCRIPTION_IS_REQUIRED;
            result = false;         
        }
    }

    if(maximumOccupancy != null)
    {
        if(numberofAdults + numberOfChildern > maximumOccupancy)
        {
            if(!tripWrapper.overOccupancyLimitConfirmation || tripWrapper.resolutionTextBlockArea == null || String.isBlank(tripWrapper.resolutionTextBlockArea))
            {
                missingDataError += '<br />  ' + OVER_OCCUPANCY_WARNING;
                result = false;   
            }
        }
    }
    if(contactPlannerSelected && unknownPlannerSelected)
    {
        missingDataError += '<br />  ' + ONLY_ON_PLANNER_CONTACT_CAN_BE_SELECTED;
        result = false;  
    }

    if(result)
    {
        Submit(result);
    }
    else
    {
        displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity.Error, String.valueOf(ERROR_SAVING_DATA + missingDataError));
        missingDataError = '';
    }       
}

// User feedback
// ApexPages.Severity Reference: CONFIRM / ERROR / FATAL / INFO / WARNING
private void displayFeedback(ApexPages.Severity msgType, String message) 
{
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(msgType, message);
    ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For valid email helper class method, here is an example

```
//  --------------------------------------------------------
//  isValidEmail - source: http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2010/01/utilizing-apex-pattern-and-matcher.html
//  --------------------------------------------------------
public static Boolean isValidEmail(String emailIn) {

  String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'; // source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html
  return String.isBlank(emailIn)
     ? false
     : Pattern.compile(emailRegex).matcher(emailIn).matches();
}
```